# Python: Restart a process and close the old shell

Tags: python, shell, operating-system

I'm using python3.5 on windows and this is the problem:

I need to close a process and restart it. I do this:

```
os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM process.exe")
call("start cmd /K  process.exe", shell=True)
```

It works well but it leave the old shell open. I would need to close it or to open the new process in the old shell.

is it possible? Thank you!

Comment: You can't easily start the application in the current console window. Once you kill process.exe, cmd (assuming that's the shell in question) will resume as the foreground process in that console. Anyway, whoever ran the application from that shell may actually want it to stay open as the foreground process at this point. If you're the one who started it, and you don't actually want the shell, then why did you run process.exe via the shell instead of running it directly?

Comment: Hi. I ran the application from the shell and I have others like that. I've 5-6 shell opened with different processes. Sometime I would need to restart one of these. 
How can I run the process directly? Will it close the old process with the same name?

Comment: You can run process.exe directly from Explorer or a shortcut, or from the cmd shell via `start "window title" process.exe`, which will open a new console with only that process attached to it. In these cases, when process.exe is killed the console automatically closes since no other process is attached to it.

Comment: I can try it only tomorrow morning. Thanks, I'll let you know

Comment: I tried call("start 'title' process.exe", shell=True) but it said that it couldn't find 'title'. I'm trying to do it from within python...

I also tried call("start cmd /K 'title'  process.exe", shell=True) but nothing...

Comment: You don't need the shell for this within Python, unless you really want a custom window title. Use `p = subprocess.Popen(['process.exe'], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)`.

Comment: If you want to use the shell, it should be `subprocess.call('start "title" process.exe', shell=True)`. The "title" text must be in double quotes.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work! If you want the upvote for the answer, you need to write an answer ;). Thank you again!